# Norton Symantec Flagging my python script as Trojan.Bayrob9

Tags: virus, antivirus, trojan

I have symantec endpoint protection on my computer. I have the python script:

```
import subprocess
import os
from ftplib import FTP
os.chdir("public_html2")
data=subprocess.check_output(["git", "diff","--name-only"]).decode("utf-8").split("\n")
entries = []
for file in data:
if file!="":
    entries.append(file.strip())

print(entries)


ftp = FTP("website here")
ftp.login("username here","password here")


for entry in entries:
    with open(entry,"rb") as fl:
        ftp.storlines("STOR "+entry,fl)
```

Everytime I run it norton symantec blocks the program and notifies me of "Trojan.bayrob9". My question is, is it more likely that I have an unrelated virus on my own computer, or that my python program is being treated as a virus.

Comment: Norton is flagging *this file* as malware, and you wonder if the infection is somewhere else? Why do you think that?

Answer (score 1):

> My question is, is it more likely that I have an unrelated virus on
>   my own computer, or that my python program is being treated as a
>   virus.

I think your python program is being treated as a virus.

**Why?**
See [here](https://www.symantec.com/security_response/attacksignatures/detail.jsp?asid=29364)

> This signature detects Trojan.Bayrob communicating and requesting
>   information from its controlling server.

And you are trying to connect to a FTP server,Couple that with trying to write data on the disk as a malware dropper and the fact python gets flagged falsely by antiviruses left and right.

Comment: I switched to Webroot and that solved the problem.

Comment: Its not about changing the vendor for anti-malware solves the problem. What if you are migrating your piece of code to some other system that has other anti-malware software. Will your code still not get flagged as malware? 
Please get your code checked with `symantec` , from the [signature details](https://www.symantec.com/security_response/attacksignatures/detail.jsp?asid=29364) , your code should be flagged if its open a `tcp` connection on `port 80` to some `C&C server`. Have you shared complete code here?